# odoo model name from controller

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

This is really a basic question but as i am novice, i need help. in odoo 8 i have model and controller and i want to know the self model name from controller.
My code are:
1) Model is (test_model.py)

```
class test_model(models.Model):
      _name='my.model'
```

2) Controller is (test_controller.py)

```
class testController(http.Controller):
       { i want to get name of my model ( my.model) here }
```

I tried self.pool() , self.pool.get() . I always gets error regarding attribute 'pool' in self.
Also i tried self.env(), i got error for 'env'
I tried http.request.env(), but i don't know what to pass in the function.

Can some one please help me.
My requirement is to get name of the model of current module from controller

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
my_model_pool = request.registry['my.model']
```

in your controller.

Comment: Thanks Gopakumar, but i need that name of the model should be dynamic, like get from self variable. so that i can get the name of module and model based on current instance of the class.

Comment: inside the model you can use self._name but from the controller it's not possible

Comment: @user280960 Sharma is right, inside the controller its not possible